# GDAL installation using brew failing on MacOS Big Sur with incompatible libtiff library version

Tags: gdal, macos, homebrew

I installed GDAL with brew on Big Sur 11.5.1 using:

> brew install gdal

All gdal commands fail though e.g.

> gdalinfo --version
>
> dyld: Library not loaded:
> /usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib   Referenced from:
> /usr/local/bin/gdalinfo   Reason: Incompatible library version:
> gdalinfo requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libtiff.5.dylib
> provides version 6.0.0

I tried

> brew doctor

without any success.

Comment: Fun fact: exact same happens when using Conda.

Comment: You can maybe create an issue here : https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/gdal.rb

Comment: Thanks @J.Monticolo, I just did that: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/83332

Comment: Raising a github issue (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/83332) also did not result in a solution to the problem.